# sqlmap base64 encoded cookie with working manual sql injection

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

I am trying to automate sql injection using sqlmap by using the following command:

```
sqlmap -r req.txt --dump
```

where `req.txt` is the request which is captured with Burp Suite. `sqlmap` couldn't find the vulnerability,

```
[WARNING] Cookie parameter 'user' does not seem to be injectable
[CRITICAL] all tested parameters do not appear to be injectable. 
Try to increase values for '--level'/'--risk' options if you wish to perform more tests. 
If you suspect that there is some kind of protection mechanism involved (e.g. WAF) maybe you could try to use option '--tamper' (e.g. '--tamper=space2comment') and/or switch '--random-agent'
```

whereas doing it manually, I can retrieve the databases using a cookie parameter which is base64 encoded.

In the request below `user` in the cookies is vulnerable. How can I exploit this vulnerability with `sqlmap`?

```
POST /WebGoat/attack?Screen=9&menu=3000 HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.16.101.135
Content-Length: 63
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjp1c2Vy
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Origin: http://172.16.101.135
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.5481.78 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Referer: http://172.16.101.135/WebGoat/attack?Screen=9&menu=3000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: user="eW91YXJldGhld2Vha2VzdGxpbms="; acopendivids=swingset,jotto,phpbb2,redmine; acgroupswithpersist=nada; JSESSIONID=C980F9E5346B158B425D490A4C8B6C6A
Connection: close

Credit=MC-673834489&SUBMIT=Buy+Now%21&user=youaretheweakestlink
```

Comment: Now try it with more verbosity to see what it is doing